# Check if return type is IEnumerable<T>

Tags: .net, ienumerable, deferred-execution

How can I check if the return type of a function is `IEnumerable<T>`?  In other words, I don't want to match `List<T>`, even though it implements `IEnumerable<T>`.  Or put even another way, how can I detect if a function has deferred execution?

Comment: would you explain what you want? with some example?

Comment: `IEnumerable<T>` by no means guarantees, nor should it even imply, deferred execution.

Comment: I'm misunderstanding.  Looking at the method signature source code doesn't do the trick?

Comment: @JaredPar - Good point.  The basis of my question was invalid.  What I want to know is whether after doing `var x = function();`, `function()` has completed running [completely] and is not maintaining any state (like `yield return`).  I have accepted Kirk's answer but also voted to close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are interacting with a `MethodInfo`?

```
Type returnType = methodInfo.ReturnType;
bool isEnumerable = returnType.IsGenericType && 
                    returnType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IEnumerable<>);
```

Of course, just because it returns `IEnumerable` doesn't mean it uses deferred execution (i.e. `yield return`) and there's no real way to check for that without decompiling the code.